# Issue while configuring eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite, husky

I am facing the following issues while adding new commit, I have project configured with eslint + husky + prettier + react + vite

```
  1:1  error  'vite' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies                      import/no-extraneous-dependencies
  2:1  error  '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen due to following:

1. First and foremost, you are using the [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import) which has a rule [`import/no-extraneous-dependencies`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md).
2. Second, your ESLint is also checking and validating `vite.config.js` for the lint errors and your `vite.config.js` has `import` statement referring to `vite` and `@vite/plugin-react-swc` packages.

Ideally, you should not lint `vite.config.js` file. You should ignore it completely:

```
// ESLint - .eslintrc / .eslintrc.js / eslint.config.js
{
  "ignorePatterns": ["vite.config.js", /* other files to ginore */],
  "rules": {
    // ... rules
  }
}
```

Or, if you still wish to lint the file but resolve this particular error, then you should put the following comment in your `vite.config.js` file:

```js
// vite.config.js

/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  // Your Vite config...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside eslint config file, add "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off" as key/value inside rules object, might fix